# How to change idle timeout asp mvc app on my shared hosting provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I have a site on a shared hosting provider. My site timeouts when on idle and can take up to 40 seconds to start up again, I want to increase the idle timeout. Under manage - Dedicated IIS application Pool, the idle timeout is set to 5 minutes I want to increase it, I called  my provider and they said I am unable to change the settings with a shared hosting account. I was thinking if there was another way Like the web.config folder to increase the timeout time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app pool is likely being recycled. There's nothing you can do about this on a shared hosting service. What you can do is send pings to the web server every N minutes. If GoDaddy recycles the app pool every 5 minutes, then send a ping to your website every 4 minutes. Doing this should extend the timeout an additional 4 minutes. If you always do this, it should not recycle unless explicitly called (or unless the host has some other recycle in place).

Optionally, you can use a monitoring service that pings and reports on your server. Here are two that may be of use to you: https://uptimerobot.com/ https://www.pingdom.com/

Answer (score 1):

Uptime services that I've tried didn't actually send HTTP requests to the web app so it didn't help in keeping it alive. However, I found a nice feature in **Application Insights** called **Availability** which lets you create recurring tests that actually send GET requests to your website, thus preventing it from recycling.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open task scheduler on your computer
2. Create a scheduled task to run every 4 minutes
3. Have it run a powershell command invoke-webreqest to your site.

It'll have the effect of someone visiting your site every 4 minutes.